# UIView Slide Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation

I am trying to create animation to swap/rotate the `UIView`s using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. I have three `UIView`s and want to add animation to bring left or right view to the front on drag. If users drag the front view to right then the left view should come to the front with an animation. Following is my code to generate the `UIView`s on landscape mode.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewRight: UIView!
    var viewFront: UIView!
    var viewLeft: UIView!

    var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() { }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        viewFront = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
        viewFront.center = view.center
        viewFront.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(viewFront)

        viewLeft = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150))
        viewLeft.center = view.center
        viewLeft.center.x = view.center.x - 100
        viewLeft.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        view.addSubview(viewLeft)

        viewRight = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150))
        viewRight.center = view.center
        viewRight.center.x = view.center.x + 100
        viewRight.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        view.addSubview(viewRight)

        view.bringSubviewToFront(viewFront)
    }
}
```

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) library is very powerful, easy to integrate and you have à lot of animations. 
You can also use [HGPageScrollView](https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView), it's a very nice Library

Hope that helps